# Apache using htaccess for browser caching

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-expires

I implemented the following to leverage browser caching in my htaccess (in the root)

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
```

however I still get warnings about browser caching from gtmetrix (pagespeed and yslow).

Have I done something wrong here? GTMetrix reports my JS resources only have an expiry of 2 days (default).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `header set` for caching by setting the expire date in the future. You can use filematch for specific file types. A year typically a good time. Edit the file types as necessary.

```
    <filesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|js|css)$">
       Header set Expires "Mon, 15 Apr 2015 20:00:01 GMT"
    </filesMatch>
```

This definitely works for me.

Comment: I tried that originally and it worked for yslow but not for pagespeed. I had to add your method and include my own for both of them to be satisfied.

Comment: Hmm, I tried it myself and it works for both Pagespeed and Yslow. The only ones it complained about were external URL which I can't control namely, the Facebook js link and the Google Plus js. Other than that mine were cached with both.

Comment: How were you generating reports? That may have something to do with it? I was using GTMetrix

Comment: I used GTMetrix as well so I could duplicate your issue. I did not have the problem with caching on either one. I also have the Yslow Chrome extension as well and that says the same thing. That is what I use in my htaccess on the server the files are being served from.